# Need script to move and rename files without overwriting duplicate filenames

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

Maybe i'm just going about this wrong and making it harder than it has to be.
This is my problem. I have 2 different scripts that download various picture files. the first downloads from email and the downloaded files go into the `/attachments/` directory. The second script copies the contents of google drive, all files and folders get copied into `~/gdrive/` directory. i want to be able to move all picture files from both these folders as well as any subfolders to `~/Pictures/$today` and prevent any overwriting in the case of duplicate file names. I don't mind having 2 separate scripts to handle the pictures in the 2 different directories, but I do need it to be able to get all files in subdirectories of the starting point. it also needs to be able to handle a variety of file extensions. my current solution adds a numbered extension such as `.~1~` after the files normal extension .jpg, .png, .tiff, etc. I dont lose any files this way but any that wind up with a backup number after the extension are rendered useless to my project. This is what I am currently using

```sh
TODAY=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
mkdir -p ~/Pictures/$TODAY &&
sudo find /attachments -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t ~/Pictures/$TODAY {} +
```

My result if there are duplicate file names looks like this:

```
DSC07286.JPG
DSC07286.JPG.~1~
```

Is there a better approach than what i am doing? Is there a way to dissect the filename parts and reorganize them and do it recursively for all files in the directory? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it (untested; uses standard lowercase variable names and puts the index just before the extension to not mess with sorting):

```
for path in ~/Pictures/"$today"/*.JPG
do
    index=0
    for duplicate_path in "$path".~[0-9]*
    do
        new_path="${duplicate_path%%.*}${index}.JPG"
        echo "$duplicate_path" "$new_path"
        ((++index))
    done
done
```

When you're confident it's doing the right thing, simply replace `echo` with `mv` to actually move the files.

Comment: I see how this would work. Could it be adapted to accommodate various image extensions too? .jpg .png .tiff etc.

Comment: To make it with any extension, you can extract the extension with: IMG_EXT=${path##*.}. Then, you add ${IMG_EXT} to "new_path" in place of the hardcoded ".JPG"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
NOW=$(date +"%D %T")

sudo mkdir -p /home/pi/Pictures/emailpics/$TODAY &&
sudo find /attachments -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t /home/pi/Pictures/emailpics/$TODAY/ {} + &&
for f in /home/pi/Pictures/emailpics/$TODAY/*.~?~
do
    fullfilename=$f
    filepath=$(dirname "$fullfilename")
    filename=$(basename "$fullfilename")
    fname="${filename%.*}"
    bkpnum="${filename##*.}"
    file="${fname%.*}"
    ext="${fname##*.}"

    sudo mv $f $filepath/$file$bkpnum.$ext
done
```

Can't say i fully understand all the syntax for the parsing bits, but it works. maybe someone else can explain what is going on.